# Why do we take root mean square velocity while finding the kinetic energy of one molecule of an ideal ga?

Tags: thermodynamics, kinetic-theory

I understand that RMS speed is usually used for a bunch of ideal gas molecules so we can get the mean of velocities but while finding the kinetic energy of a single gas molecule why do we write K.E=1/2mVrms^2 instead of K.E=1/2mv^2?[image]In the first equation we get the Vrms in terms of 1 molecule and in the 2nd equation in terms of 1 mole.Since both forms are equal they end up giving the same answer and it doesn't make sense using Vrms instead of just 'V' to find K.E of a single molecule.So my question is if a molecule has lower velocity than Vrms of the whole gas and say its velocity increases and decreases due to collision because of which we have to take Vrms for a single molecule but how can this Vrms be equal to Vrms of the whole gas as both equation 1 and 2 are equal and give the same answer?

Comment: Those are equivalent ways to get the v_RMS as the speed of a molecule with the mean (translational kinetic) energy, either using R/M either k/m.

Comment: Root *Mean* Square, mean is the statistical average of the quantity under study. It is a "picture" of an average molecule, and should be the same whatever way it is computed. To have an average, you need a large ensemble.